# Changing the heading style of references section

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}



\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the section header for my references list bolded, underlined, all capitalized, 11 pt and with C6. in front of it? I.e., currently, the section header is: **References** however I would like it to be:

[image]

---

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 9pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\renewcommand{\refname}{C6.~REFERENCES}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bibsection{%
  \section*{\underline{\refname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}}%
}%
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\underline{\textbf{C1. PROJECT TITLE}}

blkah blah

\underline{\textbf{C2. AIMS AND BACKGROUND}}


blah blah blah

\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

The size of references doesn't change when I change the font size to 9pt. I know I should use `\section` for section titles but there is a reason why I am manually creating section titles. So how can I get the references heading size to be the same as my manually made ones?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What are `C` and `6` supposed to represent? Are they part of some numbering system, or should `C6` simply be hardcoded in the heading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sure that you are using the `article` document class, just adding the following lines in your preamble should work:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{C6.~REFERENCES}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bibsection{%
  \section*{{\normalsize\underline{\refname}}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}}%
}%
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@article{reference,
author = {F Author and S Author},
journal = {Journal},
title = {Article Title},
year = {2013},
month = {10},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{natbib}

\renewcommand{\refname}{C6.~REFERENCES}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bibsection{%
  \section*{{\normalsize\underline{\refname}}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apa-good}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you also want to remove the spacing add `\vspace*{-.8\baselineskip}` in the above definition, so to have

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{C6.~REFERENCES}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\bibsection{%
  \section*{{\normalsize\underline{\refname}}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}{\MakeUppercase{\refname}}}\vspace*{-.8\baselineskip}%
}%
\makeatother
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks karlkoeller, I wanted C6 hardcoded. Also is there a way I can control the size of the title header? E.g, what if I wanted it in 20pt?

Comment: @user42388 Try adding `\Huge` (or `\huge` or `\LARGE`) before `\underline`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that, I accepted your answer, it was very helpful. Just curious, can I only add things like \small, \huge etc? Are there no commands that allow actual number specification of the text size?

Comment: @user42388 Thank you for accepting! Yes, but it is much easier to go with these commands...

Comment: Could you please show me how I can use a number specification? E.g. some of my other headers are in 11 pt, but the reference title looks slightly larger than 11 pt, any ideas?

Comment: @user42388 It's not a good practice, it's better to go with these commands. What header do you refer to? BTW: 11pt is only relative to the main body (`\normalsize`)

Comment: I have edited my initial post to explain what I mean, thanks for your kind help.

Comment: @user42388 and I have edited the answer.